# R editor that looks similar to Mathematica

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica

Is there an R editor that looks similar to Mathematica?

In Mathematica, we have cells, where we can write our code. We can then run that code, and the output shows in another cell below. The cells are independent, and in a way I can run all the functions I want independently, and if the output is too much, I just double click on the right side, and the output cell hides all info, but the first line. Also, there's this pretty colour matching so that we do not forget to which '(' matches ')' and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't tried it, you should check out Rstudio. It allows you to collapse blocks of code and you can run code blocks by selecting the lines and clicking run or `Crtl+Enter`. It Also has syntax highlighting. Not all the features you mention are there. If you have played with rstudio and want something else, that's fine. If you are especially handy with Emacs, keybindings, you might check out ESS.

Comment: There's [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebooks, which sound similar to what you're describing.

Comment: @lmo I'm using RStudio, but I don't see those features you're talking about

Comment: You have syntax highlighting. You can initiate blocks of code using: #### my block 1 ####. You can then fold up these blocks by clicking the little arrow/triangle on the left-hand side of the script panel. Navigate to a block by clicking on the little section screen with the # and the title right above the console. Similarly, self-rolled functions and loops can be wrapped up. Not sure about the prettiness, but placing your cursor next to a {([ or ])}, highlights the corresponding bracket.  You can delete all of the output (not history or objects) in the console via `Crtl-l` (lower case L).

Comment: also [beaker notebooks](http://beakernotebook.com)